# How to automatically change the wallpaper regularly

Tags: desktop-background, automatic

How can I automatically rotate my wallpaper regularly?
Is there a program or a way for doing so?

Comment: Rotate how ? Please explain a bit more, because it's unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Changing desktop background image. I thought that was clear. Please forgive my poor English.

Comment: No, I understand that you want to change background image, but how ? You want same picture to be rotated clock-wise, or counter-clockwise ? Or you mean something else when you say "rotate"  ?

Comment: I use a program called variety for this purpose - you can find it [at this location[(https://launchpad.net/variety)